# why does this javascript take the "h" out of "he"?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have this javascript code and it's supposed to display 4.0026 in the alert box after the user inputs "1 he" into the prompt, but for some reason it instead decides to take only the "h" out of "he" and use that while thinking you inputted "h" only.

```
var first=prompt("Enter first term");
        if(first==""){
            periodictable();
        }else{
            var split=first.split(" ");
            var firsttrans=split[1].replace("h", 1.008).replace("he", 4.0026);
            alert(firsttrans);
        }
```

btw ignore the function invocation `periodictable()` because it's not related to this problem.

Comment: _why does this javascript take the “h” out of “he”_ ... I have a new song title for my techno-synth-folk album, along with _lets bit shift baby_ and _kruank, kruank, that's the sound my modem makes_

Answer (score 6):

After replacing `h` you have no more `h` inside. You could change the replacement and look first for `he`, then for `h`.

```
var firsttrans = split[1].replace("he", 4.0026).replace("h", 1.008);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your replace logic. First you have check for he and if not not found then h. With your current logic, since you are replacing h first there will be no more "he" found.

```
split[1].replace("he", 4.0026).replace("h", 1.008)
```

---

Here is another clean solution. This way you can add as many pairs as you want without touching your replace code. All you need to do is just updat the changes and done.

```js
var str = "Mr.h, here is he ";
var reps = {
  "h"  : 1.008,
  "he" : 4.0026
};
str = str.replace(/he|h/gi, function(found){
  return reps[found];
});
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nina Scholz said, the replacements happen sequentially.

In case you add more elements later on, you might want to extract your data to a separate place, like so:

```js
var replacements = {
 "h": 1.008,
 "he": 4.0026
};

var first=prompt("Enter first term");
        if(first==""){
            periodictable();
        }else{
            var split=first.split(" ");
            var firsttrans=replacements[split[1]];
            alert(firsttrans);
        }
```

Comment: And the alert giving undefined. Did you test this code ?